# When is static type checking better than dynamic checking?

Tags: dynamic, static, typechecking

In which cases static type checking is better than dynamic type checking? I've seen other similar questions at SO but I didn't find an appropriate answer for this question.I also have seen advantages of both but I want an explanation about times that we prefer using static type checking.

Comment: when you say dynamic, you mean "at runtime" correct?

Comment: @aaaaaa Yes. Type checking at run time.

Comment: To me the difference would be just the runtime aspect of it then.  A performance decrease at runtime at the cost of flexibility and the time it takes to compile.  Fast compilers and "implicit types" such as c#'s `var` mitigate this cost, but don't at all avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

My opinions over statically typed languages is preferred over a dynamically typed are.

1. Statically typed language is self-documented.
2. We get fewer bugs in production.